# What is the best way to connect an embedded linux board through cable to an Android device

Tags: android, linux, usb, adk

I'am currently developing a data display which receives a data stream through wifi for displaying in an Android Tablet.

Embedded Device records data -> sends through Wifi -> Android Tablet receives and Displays data.

Wifi connection does cause a significant amount of configuration and stability issues. 
Is there a way to connect my Embedded Linux Hardware (which i can modify completly) to any Android Tablet? 
My max transfer data rate would be 16MBit/s which should be handled.

Is the ADK library sufficient? 
Do I need to write my own USB Driver for the connection?

Best regards

Comment: Use an android tablet with ethernet port

Comment: This is not practical, there aren't that much devices out there with an Ethernet Port.